# How do I read a file from a FileSystem with pyarrow.csv.read_csv?

Tags: csv, google-cloud-storage, pyarrow

I want to read a single CSV file in a google bucket with pyarrow. How do I do this?

I can create a FileSystem object with `gcsfs`, but I don't see a way to provide this to `pyarrow.csv.read_csv`.

Do I need to create some sort of file stream from the file system? What's the best way to do this?

```
import gcsfs
import pyarrow.csv as csv

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='foo')

csv.read_csv("bucket/foo/bar.csv", filesystem=fs)
```

```
TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filesystem'
```

Using pyarrow version 6.0.1

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are working with [this doc.](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#using-fsspec-compatible-filesystems-with-arrow)  You're correct that the approach listed there does not work with `read_csv` because there is no `filesystem` parameter.  We can still generally do this but the process is a bit different.

Pyarrow has its own filesystem abstraction.  If you have a pyarrow filesystem then you can first open a file and then use that file to read the CSV:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.csv as csv
import pyarrow.fs as fs

local_fs = fs.LocalFileSystem()
with local_fs.open_input_file('foo/bar.csv') as csv_file:
    csv.read_csv(csv_file)
```

Unfortunately, a `gcsfs.GCSFileSystem` is not a "pyarrow filesystem" but you have a few options.

The method `gcsfs.GCSFileSystem.open` can give you a "python file object" which you can use as input to `pyarrow.csv.read_csv`.

```
import gcsfs
import pyarrow.csv as csv

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='foo')
with fs.open("bucket/foo/bar.csv", 'rb') as csv_file:
    csv.read_csv(csv_file)
```